# Seeking Book Recommendations to Understand the Connection Between Mathematical Logic and Axiomatization

Tags: logic, reference-request

I have recently completed a discrete math course that introduced me to the basics of propositional logic and predicate logic, including concepts like logical connectives, truth tables, deductive rules, and quantifiers. However, I am still struggling to grasp the connections between these topics and the axiomatization of mathematics. In particular, I'm interested in understanding how proof techniques such as proof by contradiction and induction relate to propositional and predicate logic. Can anyone recommend a comprehensive book or resource that clarifies these connections and provides a deeper understanding of the subject?

Comment: Ethan Bloch. [Proofs and Fundamentals: A First Course in Abstract Mathematics (Springer)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Proofs_and_Fundamentals/vJLqBwAAQBAJ) and Friedrich Waismann, [Introduction to Mathematical Thinking (Dover)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Introduction_to_Mathematical_Thinking/JWLDAgAAQBAJ).